# Factorization of a number obtained by a modular multiplication operation can reveal factors of the used operands?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Consider a number $r$ obtained by:

$r=a \cdot b \mod n$

Can knowing the factorization of $r$ reveal some information (bits) of $a$ and $b$ ?